# ZF2 Doctrine multi-database Association Mapping

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to merge 3 applications with each their own database. I would like to serve as a fourth for user names, addresses, login ...
Is it possible to create a mapping between 2 entities from 2 different connection ? Or I must do it manually ?

All databases are in Mysql

- orm_default -> stores all user info (ssoid, name, addresses, login, ...)
- orm_app1 -> Application 1
- orm_app2 -> Application 2
- orm_app3 -> Application 3

PS: For configuration file, I don't know which one are needed to response. Tell me, I'll attach them.

Thx

Comment: Basically no.  If all the schemas are on the same server then you can set the table name = schema_name.table_name and it will sort of work.  But then you have schema names hard coded into your mappings.  Plus, most of the doctrine schema tools will no longer work.  I would suggest using different entity managers for each schema and doing the linking manually.

Comment: Each scheme has its own entity manager, I was actually the link manually, but I wanted to know if it was possible to do so "automatic"